# How to take screenshot using Selenium RC using c# in IE8?

Tags: c#, selenium-rc, screenshot

I am using Selenium RC using c# and need to take screenshot for the test case failed, I have to perform these test on IE 8.

I got lot of tutorials for Firefox but didn't find any for the IE8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try the screenshot function you found for Firefox?  What did it do?  Error message?  Please edit the question and add more details about what you've done and how it isn't working.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: I cannot try screenshot function for Firefox as my application is only IE compatible, it does not support Firefox. i already tried for this function but it doesn't work as i dont want to have firefox used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Selenium Web Driver to take a screenshot of IE pretty easily.  The code would look something like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
TakeScreenshot(driver, @"C:\screenshot.png");
```

You can download the Web Driver here:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
Add it to your project and you are off and running.

Comment: I have already complete automation done on Selenium RC, now i cannot move on that. i just need screen shots for the test case failing so that report can have actual prob/